# .each loop adds adds another array at the bottom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, render

When I try to render a list paginated jobs, at the bottom though the array of all of those item is included as well. What is happenning? 
http://take.ms/9HtCa

**jobs_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @joblist = Job.page(params[:page]).per(20) 
   render 'jobs/index'
end
```

**index.html.haml**

```
.row-fluid
  .span8.hidden-desktop
    =render 'job'

  .span4
    .center
      .add-job
        =link_to "добавить вакансию", new_job_path
```

**_job.html.haml**

```
%span
  =@joblist.each do |job|
    %ul
      .job-item
        %span
          .fl-l
            =job.title
          .fl-r
            =succeed ',' do
              =Country.find_by_id(job.country_id).name
            =City.find_by_id(job.city_id).name
          %br
        %span
          .fl-l
            =job.jobtype
        %br

  =paginate @joblist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` should be `-`

`=` renders output but `-` evaluates a ruby expression.

[Ruby Evaluation in Haml](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#ruby_evaluation).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `=` before `@joblist.each`. It is displaying value returned by expression and each is returning array it iterates over.